# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and reusing Bundle ID

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, bundle

Here's an interesting think I've observed and which has puzzled me for some time now.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 which I deploy multiple OSGi bundles on.

When I want to replace the bundles with new versions/revisions I have to `uninstall` and then `install` bundles.

Normally, I'd assume Glassfish can reuse old bundle ids that aren't present any more, but it just continues. For example, let's say that Glassfish bundles go to ID of 100, and my own bundles start go from 101 to 200.

When I uninstall old bundles and install new ones, I'd assume that the bundle ID in range 101-200 would be reusable.

Instead, my new bundles have their IDs from 201 to 300.

I'm uninstalling them like this:

```
uninstall <bundle id>
```

and installing like this:

```
install file:<path-to-bundle>
```

How to resolve this problem so that Glassfish reuses old bundle IDs?

Edit:

I have found a folder named `bundle0` in `glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix` which contains a file named `bundle.id` with a single number, which seems to be something like a DB sequence, noting the last bundle id used.

In order for me to manually change the starting bundle id with the following bundle installations, I have to do the following, in this order:

1. Uninstall my bundles via GoGo console
2. Stop Glassfish
3. Delete `bundle<ID>` folders of my bundles in `glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix`
4. Change the number in `bundle.id` file to some reasonable number
5. Start Glassfish - it will increment the number in `bundle.id` file
6. Install new versions of my bundles

As you can imagine, I do not want to do this every time I want to do a release/upgrade.
Can Glassfish do this by itself, or do I need to create a script of some sort that will do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OSGi spec requires bundle ids to not be reused. Note: you can update a bundle in place rather than uninstall/install. When you update, the bundle id is preserved.

Comment: What happens when you want to update your bundle with a higher version one, and what when you want to update it with the same version one?

Will it update the bundle in both cases, or only in 1st?

Comment: The OSGi framework does not care about the versions when updating a bundle. It will replace the bundle with whatever you provide in the update call. So you can upgrade and downgrade a bundle via update.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to keep the same IDs? As BJ mentioned you're not supposed to do this, so you're probably approaching another problem the wrong way.